# Can I run Xamarin Studio in a virtualized Windows 10 environment?

Tags: mobile, xamarin, virtual-machine

Can I run Xamarin Studio in a virtualized Windows 10 environment? or

Can I use Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise under a virtualized Windows 10 environment to do Xamarin mobile application development?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run VS2017 in a VM.  Note that Xamarin Studio (XS) is now only supported on the Mac.